# Dynamic price in Buy item button and hidden notify_url

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I want to create PayPal button with dynamic price (depending from the item)
and hidden notify url.
The "amount" input is not working with saved and encrypted buttons,
but if I use plain text the notify_url is visible in the code.
Is the a way it to be hidden or encrypted and in the same time to have
working amount input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to specify the notify_url in code, specifying the notify_url as a hidden input only overrides the one that you have specified in your paypal account. About the price, there are lots of possibilities with paypal starting from creating a simple "buy now" button with dropdowns above to select price+product to paypal api's where you can generate buttons in your application

Comment: I don`t need a drop down, in the matter of fact it`s only one product but the price can be changed in the future, and I don`t want to change the button. I`ll check is the price correct after the IPN.
Thanks I`ll check about setting the notify_url in my account.

Comment: btw, you must have a premier or business account, or for development just go to paypal's sandbox and create as much accounts as you need and exercise with creating/using buttons in there